# Is it possible to allow an app to be installed on the SD card for Android 6 only?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have an Android app which for now can only be installed on the internal memory:

> android:installLocation="internalOnly"

because it uses widgets, services which wouldn't work properly if the app was moved on the SD card ([doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#ShouldNot))

I would like to enable the app to use Android 6 Adoptable storage and am wondering if there's a way to only do this for users running Android 6+...

Do you know if this is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set it in Manifest, but you can always check that runtime and if anything is not meeting your requirements, just show error dialog to the user.

Comment: This is a Manifest setting. This cannot be changed a t runtime